# How to design handling of requests using multiple threads in Delphi?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, windows-services

I am new to architecture and design of multi-threaded applications.

How can I design the following case and if any design pattern exists, it is even more good.

We need to design a windows service that can do the following.

SQL Server Database has two tables called Organization and Events table which holds the list of organizations and list of events happening in that organization respectively.

Windows service needs to handle the events of every organization asynchronously. 
Windows service reads the list of organizations from organization table and creates a thread for each organization.  Each organization thread, polls Events table every 2 secs reads the events into an Event List. Another object (dispatcher) must be invoked when something is put/available in the Event list and dispatcher object creates and runs an event handler thread to handle each of these events. Once the event is handled, event handler thread should be terminated.

There can be an multiple sources for events which puts the events in Event list.

Using Delphi 2009 and SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

Please help.

Comment: why are so many "organization" threads required if all they do is polling? One polling thread would be enough IMHO.

Comment: also I would consider providing a way to 'notify' the service when an events gets inserted: via IPC or TCP or UDP or HTTP or a named pipe or mailslot, COM+, MSMQ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you create a thread per organisation? The only reason I can think of is when you want to be able to configure different polling times per organisation. Otherwise, I'd just have one polling thread that fetches all events since the last poll and processes those events.

For processing the events, you can use a queue and a pool of workers to process them (have a look at [OmnithreadLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/), so processing the events (which may be time-consuming, I don't know), can be multi-threaded.

If you like, you can make sure that only one event per organisation is processed simultaneously, although you should wonder if that makes sense at all.

So, I would have:

- 1 polling thread to fetch new events and put them in a queue.
- 1 queue for processing those events.
- Any number of workers to process the queue, preferably based on the number of cpu cores rather than the number of organisations.

If you need to do event messaging throughout your organisation, you may also want to take a look at a tool like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). It may be a good idea to fetch the events and put them in RabbitMQ right away, after which that tool can distribute them.